# Play!: value "bars" is not a member of "model.Foo"..?

Tags: scala, playframework, slick

Sort of new to Playframework. What am I doing wrong here?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thx

Uhm, why the down vote? If there's something I'm missing, you could comment so that I can edit it in. Just trying to get an answer & it would suck to have my question closed before I can get an answer.

---

Here's my code:

```
package model

case class Foo(id: Option[FooId],
                name: String) extends WithId[FooId]

object Foos extends IdTable[FooId, FOO]("FOOS") {

  def bars = Vector(Query(Bars).filter(_.fooId === id)) // Here is where "bars" is defined
}
```

And here's my view:

```
@(foo: model.Foo)

@foo.name
<ul>
    @foo.bars { b =>
       <li>
         @b.id
       </li>
     }
</ul>
```

And here's the error:

```
value bars is not a member of model.Foo
```

Comment: Well it behaves correctly. There is no bars inside Foo.

Comment: @Jatin Check under `object Foos` -- there is where I define "bars". I understand I'm not using `val` or w/e the compiler's complaining about but I would like to know how I can fix it to make it compile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is quite correct. Foo objects do not have bars members. Nor are they methods that take a {b => ...} closure.

What you are probably trying to do is this:

```
@(foo: model.Foo)

@foo.name
<ul>
    @{Query(model.Foos).filter(_.id === foo.id).flatMap(_.bars)}.foreach { b =>
       <li>
         @b.id
       </li>
     }
</ul>
```

Be aware that you probably run into https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-3764 with this which will reveal itself as a SlickException. To solve this use

```
class Bars extends IdTable[BarId, Bar]("BARS") {...}
val Bars = new Bars
```

instead of

```
object Bars extends IdTable[BarId, Bar]("BARS") {...}
```

And you need to place the val somewhere non top-level of course. Alternatively you can work around the bug by placing your table objects in some non-static location (a class or trait). The bug isn't triggered in Slick 2 anymore by the way.

Comment: I'm getting an error: `not found: value Query` when using it in my view

Comment: You probably know much better than me how to fix your imports in Play templates, but you could just use the fully qualified scala.slick.lifted.Query.

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean now. I just thought it was bad practice mixing these types of imports with view logic -- Thx for clearing this up :)

Comment: If you use fully qualified names or imports doesn't really matter. Not sure how to do imports in a Play template though. The question if you use Queries within your view or not is a design decision. Personally I think I like pushing query objects all the way into the view, but in this case I would probably write the query in the controller and pass it as a value into the template and execute it there. Other people may prefer to execute them in the controller and pass the results in. In any case, glad I could help :).